# firefox: remove "Open Link in New Tab" from the right-click menu

Tags: firefox, css

How can I remove "Open Link in New Tab" from the right-click menu?

This [post](https://support.mozilla.org/gu-IN/questions/1366880) suggests adding the following code to `userChrome.css`:

```
#context_openANewTab,
#context_openANewTab + menuseparator {
  display: none !important;
}
```

but it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id for the element is now `context-openlinkintab`.

Update `userChrome.css` with:

```
#context-openlinkintab {
  display: none !important;
}
```